# What exact time do Android devices execute the Daylight Saving Changes?

Tags: clock, date-and-time

I believe the Windows OS in general makes the Fall DST change at 3.00am on the last Sunday of October, and the Spring change at 2.00am on the last Sunday of March. Could someone enlighten me on the exact times that the Android OS, in general, (or 4.3 specifically) makes the DST changes?

Comment: If you are a resident of the United States, you have both those datetimes wrong. What country of residence? As a rule, an Operating System adopts the DST rules of the country of residence. To apply alternate rules of DST would inhibit proper billing for phone and data plans which depend on time accuracy.

Comment: I believe what I have are the defaults within Central European Time.

Comment: Good to know. I hope it worked out as my comments and the answers reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, every OS makes the change at the officially scheduled time for your timezone. This is different in different timezones, but if you've previously observed your Windows clock changing at a particular time, you'll see any other OS changing at the same time. The exact time is set by the government: programmers don't just pick a time they think would be nice.

Comment: If I may ask, do you know if this is done with some scheduled process or if it's simply depending on something like NTP?

Comment: Most mobile devices don't use NTP by default. Time is rather depending on the provider. See [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/52557/16575).

Comment: @dotVezz If you have another question, use the **Ask Question** button in the corner.